# VariantManagement for sap.m.Table in SAPUI5 Fiori elements OData v4 app

Tags: javascript, xml, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I wanna add VariantManagement for my `sap.m.Table`. As an option I chose `sap.ui.fl.variants.VariantManagement` with `sap.m.p13n.Engine`.

As an example I use the sample from the documentation:
[https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.p13n.Engine/sample/sap.m.sample.p13n.Engine/code](https://stackoverflow.com)

To be honest right now I just copy pasted the code from the example and I immediately got some problems.

Here is the code:

```
handleStateChange: function(oEvt) { 
            var oTable = this.byId("persoTable");
            var oState = oEvt.getParameter("state");

            if (!oState) {
                return;
            }

            var aSorter = [];
            oState.Sorter.forEach(function(oSorter) {
                aSorter.push(new Sorter(this.oMetadataHelper.getProperty(oSorter.key).path, oSorter.descending));
            });

            oState.Groups.forEach(function(oGroup) {
                var oExistingSorter = aSorter.find(function(oSorter){
                    return oSorter.sPath === oGroup.key;
                });

                if (oExistingSorter) {
                    oExistingSorter.vGroup = true;
                } else {
                    aSorter.push(new Sorter(this.oMetadataHelper.getProperty(oGroup.key).path, false, true));
                }
            }.bind(this));

            oTable.getColumns().forEach(function(oColumn, iIndex){
                oColumn.setVisible(false);
            });

            **oState.Columns.forEach(function(oProp, iIndex){
                var oCol = this.byId(oProp.key);
                oCol.setVisible(true);

                oTable.removeColumn(oCol);
                oTable.insertColumn(oCol, iIndex);
            }.bind(this));**

            var aCells = oState.Columns.map(function(oColumnState) {
                return new Text({
                    text: "{" + oColumnState.key + "}"
                });
            });

            oTable.bindItems({
                templateShareable: false,
                path: '/items',
                sorter: aSorter,
                template: new ColumnListItem({
                    cells: aCells
                })
            });

        }
```

My problem is connected with **`oState`**.
I just get all the columns from a personalization dialog with no chance to recognize which of them are checked by user and which aren't.

I hope that somebody just faced the same problem while implementation this feature and understand my pain and can explain how I can fix it.

I would appreciate any hint how to deal with it:)

I have a simple `sap.m.Table` and I need to add VariantManagement with personalization dialog.
So while researching the documentation I found an interesting example: [https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.p13n.Engine/sample/sap.m.sample.p13n.Engine/code](https://stackoverflow.com).

But unfortunately this example has its own minuses. So I decided to ask somebody else how to handle these problems, maybe somebody has already dealt with this sample and can help me with it.